# How can I fill the lag with leading non-zero values?

Tags: r, lag, locf

I can lag a vector like this, keeping/dublicating the initial value '1':

```
x <- c(1,0,0,0,0)
zoo::na.locf(lag(x,1), fromLast = T)
[1] 1 1 0 0 0
```

But if there is a leading '0' in the x vector, the following '1' is not repeated:

```
x <- c(0,1,0,0,0)
zoo::na.locf(lag(x,1), fromLast = T)
[1] 0 0 1 0 0
```

How can I repeat/keep the '1' if it is not leading?
The result should look like this:

```
0 1 1 0 0
```

In other words: I want to fill the gap/lag between the original position of the first non-zero value and its lagged position with the first non-zero value. Here is a little more complex example:

```
c(0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0)
```

should become

```
c(0,0,0,1,1,2,3,0,0,0)
```

by `lag 1`

and

```
c(0,0,0,1,1,1,1,2,3,0)
```

by `lag 3`

Comment: Is that `dplyr::lag` or `stats::lag`? (I'm assuming the former ...)

Comment: it is dplyr::lag

Comment: `pmax(x, lag(x, 1, default = 0))`?

Comment: this works for lag 1, but lag 2 `pmax(x, lag(x, 2, default = 0))` should return `0 1 1 1 0` (instead of `0 1 0 1 0`) and it should also work for e.g. `x <- c(0,1,2,3,0)` `pmax(x, lag(x, 2, default = 0))` resulting in `0 1 1 1 2` (instead of `0 1 2 3 3`)

In other words: I want to insert the first non-zero-value for lag times and then bring the initial value series.

Comment: I guess I don't understand what you think is happening with the second vector in your question (`c(0,1,0,0,0)`). When you `lag` it, the leading `0` shifts over to the right, which is correct. Are you saying that you want all `0`s starting from the left to convert to `1`s until the first original `1` is found? What happens with `c(0,0,0,1,0)`?

Comment: I updated the question with a more complex example.

Comment: What should happen if all values are `0`? Would you just want the same vector of `0`s as the result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Extract out the leading `0`s, `lag()` the remaining vector with the first value as `default`, then add back the leading `0`s. Wrapped in a helper function:

```
library(dplyr)

my_lag <- function(x, n = 1L) {
  if (all(x == 0)) return(x)
  x_0 <- x[cumall(x == 0)]
  x_1 <- x[!cumall(x == 0)]
  c(x_0, lag(x_1, n = n, default = x_1[[1]]))
}
```

Results with your example vectors:

```
x1 <- c(1,0,0,0,0)
x2 <- c(0,1,0,0,0)
x3 <- c(0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0)

my_lag(x1)
# 1 1 0 0 0 

my_lag(x2)
# 0 1 1 0 0

my_lag(x3)
# 0 0 0 1 1 2 3 0 0 0

my_lag(x3, 3)
# 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 3 0
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this function.

```r
mylag <- function(x, n = 1L, default = 1L) {
  r <- rle(x == 0)
  if (r$values[1]) x <- x[-seq_len(r$lengths[1])]
  x <- dplyr::lag(x, n = n, default = default)
  c(if (r$values[1]) rep(0L, r$lengths[1]), x)
}
```

Demo:

```r
x <- c(0,1,0,0,0)
mylag(x, 1)
# [1] 0 1 1 0 0
mylag(x, 2)
# [1] 0 1 1 1 0
mylag(x, 3)
# [1] 0 1 1 1 1

x <- c(0,0,0,1,2,3,0,0,0,0)
mylag(x, 1)
#  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 2 3 0 0 0
mylag(x, 2)
#  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 2 3 0 0
mylag(x, 3)
#  [1] 0 0 0 1 1 1 1 2 3 0
```